# Can generics have a constraint of several specific types without extending?

Tags: typescript

My goal is to make use of strict typing to ensure that objects are properly formatted. I'd like to be able to specify a few valid formats that must be followed and enforce them.

```
interface TypeA { A: void; }
interface TypeB { B: void; }
interface TypeC { C: void; }

type Type = TypeA | TypeB | TypeC;

interface BaseItem<T extends Type> { name: string; data: T; }

type Item = BaseItem<TypeA> | BaseItem<TypeB> | BaseItem<TypeC>;

const collection: Item[] = [
  { name: 'A', data: { A: null } },
  { name: 'B', data: { B: null } },
  { name: 'C', data: { C: null } },
];

class Example<T extends Type> {
  item: BaseItem<T>;

  add(item: BaseItem<T>) {
    this.item = item;
    collection.push(item); // Error on `item`

    /**
     * Argument of type 'BaseItem<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Item'.
     *   Type 'BaseItem<T>' is not assignable to type 'BaseItem<TypeA>'.
     *     Type 'T' is not assignable to 'TypeA'.
     *       Type 'Type' is not assignable to type 'TypeA'.
     *         Property 'A' is missing in the type 'TypeB' but required in type 'TypeA'.
     */
  }
}
```

In the code above, the type `Item` is used to enforce the format of the objects in the `collection` array. This gives an idea of how I plan to make use of this format.

Also in the code above, I attempt to use a generic for the `Example` class. The idea is that I may want several attributes of my class to ensure they are all using the shared generic at any given moment. And although the generic extends the valid type, I understand that it could theoretically support types beyond it (e.g. `BaseItem<TypeA> & { more: string }`).

I understand why it doesn't work in its current state. What I don't understand is how I would accomplish what I want.

Is there way to use a generic to strictly match a type of unions instead of extending a type of unions? Like, instead of `<T extends Type>`, is there something like `<T is Type>`? Or, is there a different way to approach this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fix/make work? The current code yield error because `BaseItem` is a subtype of `Item`, not the other way around. I don't see why `Type` is in question?

Comment: If you want `T is Type`, then literally, you don't need a generic cus you already know it's `Type`.

Comment: The end goal is to enable the class to have multiple attributes and methods using the `T` type. This would allow any child classes to be more specific (e.g. `class Specific extends Example<TypeA> { ... }`) and enforce adherence to whatever type is specified.

Comment: If I were to simply use `Type`, then I'd have no way of making sure that `TypeA` is use over `TypeB` in a child class that should only be using `TypeA`.

Comment: Then you've already got what you want, `<T extends Type>` means what you refer as `<T is Type>`. Like I said, the error you got is not related to `T`

Comment: @hackape Your comments made me realized I messed up the example. I've fixed it. `BaseItem<TypeA>` was supposed to be part of the `Item` type's union.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to categorize this, a limitation? It looks buggy to me though. Here's how you can fix it:

```
interface TypeA { A: void; }
interface TypeB { B: void; }
interface TypeC { C: void; }

type Type = TypeA | TypeB | TypeC;

interface BaseItem<T extends Type> { name: string; data: T; }

type Item = BaseItem<TypeA> | BaseItem<TypeB> | BaseItem<TypeC>;

const collection: Item[] = [
  { name: 'A', data: { A: null } },
  { name: 'B', data: { B: null } },
  { name: 'C', data: { C: null } },
];

class Example<T extends Type> {
  item: BaseItem<T>;

  // notice this conditional type, see the irony here?
  // everything `extends any`, so this expression reduce to
  // just `BaseItem<T>`, never `never`, so why the trouble?
  add(item: T extends any ? BaseItem<T> : never) {
    this.item = item;
    collection.push(item);  // cus this way error magically disappear :)
  }
}
```

I kinda get tired with all the tricks involved when using TS. This is [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), yeah yet another fancy name, click through if you're interested. Personally I don't know how to justify this behavior.

Comment: I'm not happy with the current behavior how TS handle generic type param. It's not sure about everything, even with the constraint that strong.

Comment: The link made me realize that I could use that technique to create an `ItemByType<T extends Type>` distributive conditional type with the value `T extends TypeA ? BaseItem<TypeA> : ...` for all item types. It's a bit... verbose, but it works.

Comment: @KOVIKO upvote/accept would be nice if it helps you.

Comment: I don't feel I can accept this as the answer since I'm not sure the implications of using `any` in this context. But an upvote is deserved!